# Keeping KeystoneJS code updated with the main branch after customization

Tags: heroku, github, keystonejs

I have a fresh Installation of KeystoneJS nicely deployed to Heroku with the "*Deploy to Heroku*" button. I also cloned the source into my own git repo.

Now I'm ready to make some changes to the code. 
What I want is to **add** my customized files rather than making any change to the original KeystoneJS files.

This way I can **keep the KeystoneJS part of my project continuously up to date with the main KeystoneJS project**, making updates just a matter of syncing some files.

I noticed that KeysoneJS provide the nice feature of the "*updates*" so my idea is to put a file ( for example updates/0.0.5-customize.js ) with some code that **say to the server not to send the default index file but a customized version** when a client visit the web root.

The problem I face is that I don't even know if this could be done. I'm sorry for not showing any code, but since I'm trying to solve a common problem, I want to know if I'm on the right track and if any of you managed to solve it this way or in an even better way. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the least modification to original files is the index.js view in the routes/views folder.

Change this:

> view.render('index');

to this:

> view.render('myindex');

And create the myindex.jade view.